# Fundamental group $\pi_1 (G/K) = K$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I want to prove following fundamental group property. 
\begin{align}
\pi_1(G/K) = K
\end{align}

---

Let $G$ be a universal covering group, and $K$ be either its center or a subgroup of its center. 
If $G$ is semi-simple, $K$ is finite group, by defining the elements $g$ and $kg$,  to be equivalent (where $g\in G$ and $k\in K$), 
\begin{align}
\pi_1(G/K) = K
\end{align}

Is there any idea for proving this theorem?

---

I saw this theorem, from computing fundamental group of $SO(3)$ 
\begin{align}
\pi_1(SO(3)) = \pi_1(SU(2)/Z_2) = Z_2
\end{align}
Note $\pi_1(SU(2))=0$ $i.e$, simply connected.

Comment: How about $\pi_1(U(1)/\mathbb{Z}_n)=\pi_1(U(1)=\mathbb{Z}$ but which is not $\mathbb{Z}_n$???